# Can gradient color in animated drawable XML?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, animatedvectordrawable

I used gradient color in vectors. It's working. I want to use gradient color on animated vectors but it is cannot be working. I can't see a problem in my XML code. I don't know if this possible or should I use another method. If it's not possible, I want to know why.

**Animated drawable file.**

```
<animated-vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
<aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        android:name="vector"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">
        <path
            android:name="path"
            android:pathData="M 1.218 7.957 L 1.218 15.783 L 22.779 15.783 L 22.779 7.957">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:endX="0.0"
                    android:endY="50.0"
                    android:startX="24.0"
                    android:startY="50.0"
                    android:type="linear">
                    <item android:color="#FF70C8BB" android:offset="0.0"/>
                    <item android:color="#FF0964AE" android:offset="1.0"/>
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </vector>
</aapt:attr>
<target android:name="path">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="500"
                android:valueFrom="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                android:valueTo="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="500"
                android:duration="500"
                android:valueFrom="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                android:valueTo="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="1000"
                android:duration="500"
                android:valueFrom="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                android:valueTo="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="1500"
                android:duration="500"
                android:valueFrom="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                android:valueTo="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
        </set>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fake it. Fade out your path while fading in another path with the other gradient you want, like so:

1. make a copy of path: path2
2. set the other gradient in path2
3. set path2 fillAlpha to 0
4. make a duplicate of the path animations where you target path2
5. add a fillAlpha objectAnimation to both animations sets where fillAlpha goes from 1 to 0 and path2 fillAlpha goes from 0 to 1 instead

Ex:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
```

Your full code would look something like this:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData="M 1.218 7.957 L 1.218 15.783 L 22.779 15.783 L 22.779 7.957">
                <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                    <gradient
                        android:endX="0.0"
                        android:endY="50.0"
                        android:startX="24.0"
                        android:startY="50.0"
                        android:type="linear">
                        <item android:color="#FF70C8BB" android:offset="0.0"/>
                        <item android:color="#FF0964AE" android:offset="1.0"/>
                    </gradient>
                </aapt:attr>
            </path>
            <path
                android:name="path2"
                android:fillAlpha="0"
                android:pathData="M 1.218 7.957 L 1.218 15.783 L 22.779 15.783 L 22.779 7.957">
                <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                    <gradient
                        android:endX="0.0"
                        android:endY="50.0"
                        android:startX="24.0"
                        android:startY="50.0"
                        android:type="linear">
                        <item android:color="#FFFFC8BB" android:offset="0.0"/>
                        <item android:color="#FF0964FF" android:offset="1.0"/>
                    </gradient>
                </aapt:attr>
            </path>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                    android:valueTo="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="500"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                    android:valueTo="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                    android:valueTo="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="1500"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                    android:valueTo="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
                    android:duration="2000"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                    android:valueTo="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="500"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 7.957 0.783 L 7.957 22.957 L 15.913 22.957 L 15.913 0.783"
                    android:valueTo="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 7.957 7.957 L 7.957 15.783 L 15.913 15.783 L 15.913 7.957"
                    android:valueTo="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="1500"
                    android:duration="500"
                    android:valueFrom="M 1.043 7.957 L 1.043 15.783 L 22.957 15.783 L 22.957 7.957"
                    android:valueTo="M 1.043 0.783 L 1.043 22.957 L 22.957 22.957 L 22.957 0.783"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
                    android:duration="2000"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```